# Phonegap unable to post SSL with Android 2.3

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, saml-2.0

The phonegap app that was developed was able to login using SSL with other android devices. However, when I tested with and android 2.3.3 device, I was unable to log in. I have searched aroundand found out that 2.3.3 does not support SSL. Does any body have a work around for android 2.3.3 to support SSL? for this instance is sso saml 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Https connection difference between Android 2.3 and 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155914/https-connection-difference-between-android-2-3-and-4)