# SSL Error during Facebook Login in Android

Tags: android, ssl, android-studio, facebook-login

I am implementing Facebook Login in my App but its not working on **Api 2.3.6**

**I have tested the App in Emulator and its working Fine upto Api 23**

**Also it's working in Device with API 21 but not in 2.3.6**

The Error is related to **SSL**

Bcoz I have read in an SO answer that,

- *in Api level 2.3.6 all connections and  authorizations are handled by HTTPS only 
  while in Api levels above 2.3.6 its not the HTTPS that does every task*
- *Also I have noticed that whenever I am trying to call any URL starting

  with **HTTPS** it's not giving the final result but gets silently stopped as was the case 
  with Googles Direction Api.*

**Below is the StackTrace I am getting in 2.3.6 :**

```
 V/webkit: LoadListener.handleSslErrorRequest():   
  url:https://m.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?
    return_scopes=true&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&redirect_uri
    =fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&sdk=android-  
    4.5.1&e2e=%7B%22init%22%1232%7D&client_id=1234&default_audience=friends   
    primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=*.facebook.com,O=Facebook\,  
    Inc.,L=Menlo Park,ST=CA,C=US;
    Issued by: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1223,CN=Cyberoam SSL  
    CA_C016700030,OU=Cyberoam Certificate 
    Authority,O=Elitecore,L=Ahmedabad,ST=Gujarat,C=IN;

    I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:52994]
    I/webkit/webview: WebView.stopLoading()
    D/webkit/webview: WebView.stopLoading(): webcorethread is initialized
    I/webkit/webview: WebView.stopLoading()
    D/webkit/webview: WebView.stopLoading(): webcorethread is initialized
    W/System.err:     at    
    com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:173)
    W/System.err:  at     
    com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:139)
    W/System.err:     at    
    com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult
    (CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
    W/System.err:     at     
    com.hogo.integrationapp.FirstActivity.onActivityResult
    (FirstActivity.java:179)
    W/System.err:     at   
    android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3975)
    W/System.err:     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2629)
    W/System.err:     at  
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2675)
    W/System.err:     at   
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:156)
    W/System.err:     at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1030)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    W/System.err:     at   
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    W/System.err:     at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run\
    (ZygoteInit.java:969)
    W/System.err:     at   
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
    W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any Easy way to solve it  ?

Also I want to understand why this is happening ?

I am using Facebook Sdk 4.5.1

**For API 4.4.2 :
The Error was due to a File Transfer App open in my Device, when i closed it the error was gone**

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have seen similar error while using 2.3. This issue is related to SSL and OS. There was a bug raised against OS. Did you try in any other device with higher API level?

Comment: Try importing the certificate manually. This is just to make sure its due to SSL error.

Comment: @BaluSKT i have edited my question

Comment: I think you should look into here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574870/no-peer-certificate-error-in-android-2-3-but-not-in-4

Comment: Please post the stacktract as text. Images can't be searched and hence your question will not be helpful community in the future.

Comment: @Sufian i have added the Stacktrace

Comment: @MarkySmarky I followed your link and i followed the accepted answer and found that the first to points may be related to my problem ,so i used openssl command and found that *.facebook.com is using Digicert CA and i checked the list of trusted CA's on Android 2.3.6 in the link and found Digicert in the list.So that concludes that my problem is related to the second point ie SNI.And i think facebook supports SNI bcoz of this link https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/securely-developing-on-mobile/10151408888270766/ , So what should i do to support SNI in my App?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782882/how-do-we-enable-sni-in-httpclient-4-4-on-android

Comment: Can you try to bypass the SSL in your application?