# How Do We Enable SNI in HttpClient 4.4+ on Android?

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to work out recipes for using SNI with major HTTP stacks on modern versions of Android. This includes Apache's separate HttpClient library (*not* the version baked into Android itself, which is dead and gone).

It appears that recent versions of HttpClient do not support SNI out of the box. When I use the `'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'` artifact, I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '...' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=...)
at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:466)
at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
```

(host names redacted with `...`)

[This HttpClient issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1522) has some code that purports to address this. However, it is not clear exactly how to use it. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571582/115145) helps a bit with an implementation. However, that in turn crashes with an equivalent exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=...)
at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:466)
at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
```

This does not surprise me. The proposed workaround (replace the real host name with the empty string) struck me as rather odd.

[This Stack Overflow question-and-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854543/how-to-enable-sni-in-http-request-using-apache-httpcomponents-httpclient) basically say "use Java 1.7", which is not a viable option for Android.

So, has anyone worked out a recipe for enabling SNI with an Android-compatible HttpClient 4.4+ environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this version of [SSLConnectionSocketFactory](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient-android/tags/4.3.5.1/src/main/java/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java) instead of the one shipped with Marek Sebera's fork of HttpClient. It contains this Andriod specific bit of code. Last time I tested SNI with the official Apache port of HttpClient 4.3 it worked just fine.

```
// Android specific code to enable SNI
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Enabling SNI for " + target);
    }
    try {
        Method method = sslsock.getClass().getMethod("setHostname", String.class);
        method.invoke(sslsock, target);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SNI configuration failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
// End of Android specific code
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is from 4.3, and it depends on stuff that doesn't exist anymore. However, this *does* show me where I can introduce that `setHostname` reflection hack, which I am using successfully with `HttpURLConnection` (to the extent any reflection hack represents "success"). I already have a custom subclass of `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` with a custom `createLayeredSocket()`. Rather than chaining to the superclass implementation, I'll try cloning that bit of code and blending in the reflection hack.

Comment: I wound up cloning [the 4.4.1 edition of `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.4.1/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java) and introducing the code from your answer into `createLayeredSocket()` in the same spot as in the `4.3.5.1` version that you linked to (after `prepareSocket()`, before `startHandshake()`). That seems to be working. I'm aiming to get this rolled into a library eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad that helped. Please consider reporting this issue to Marek and asking him to integrate the fix into his fork.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/issues/7), though I'll admit that I am not especially hopeful.

Comment: I cannot get your connection Factory working. And i think your bugfix is not even called for android lower than API LV 17 because the wher you call this code has a "@TargetApi(17)"