# Prevent SSL_do_handshake failure when using cz.msebera.android.httpclient on older Android platforms

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslhandshakeexception

Given an Android app that uses httpclient to connect to a third party web site, how can I get a successful SSL connection from an older Android device?

Earlier, both current and older Android versions worked, but the third party web site changed their SSL configuration.  This precipitated an error, but only on the older Android platforms:

```
System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
```

After doing some research ([google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008293)), I thought I might try to remove `SSLv3` from the list of available protocols.  I have been able to do that, and also have narrowed the number of cipher suites, but still have the `SSLException` problem.

The code, which uses `httpclient-4.4.1.2`, is patched to allow SNI, and works on newer Android (API 22), but not on an older Android (API 15) is this:

```
            nHttpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).setDefaultCookieStore(nCookieStore).build();
```

Here is some code I've been experimenting with.  Although I am able to remove SSLv3, I'm still unable to establish a secure connection:

```
            HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
            SSLContextBuilder contextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
            contextBuilder.useProtocol("TLSv1");
            SSLContext sslContext = contextBuilder.build();
            clientBuilder.setSslcontext(sslContext);
            nHttpclient = clientBuilder.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).setDefaultCookieStore(nCookieStore).build();
```

The above code limits the protocols to include `TLSv1` (no longer includes `SSLv3`.  Also, I have temporarily altered `SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket()` so that the socket only includes cipher suites included in both new and old Android platforms.  In other words, I removed a bunch of suites that were not reported as available on a new Android platform.

So, limiting to `TLSv1` and limiting to newer cipher suites, I'm still getting the error and am not able to establish a secure connection.

Logging on older Android:

```
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Enabled protocols: [TLSv1]
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: !!Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Starting handshake
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec: Connection discarded
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection: http-outgoing-1: Close connection
```

The same code running on newer Android:

```
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Starting handshake
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory: Secure session established
```

## Summary

It must be a common problem to enable older Android platforms to be able to use `httpclient-4.4.1.2` (or similar) when the sites being accessed have been updated to newer SSL/TLS standards.

My experiments with `API 15` indicate that having httpclient code that manages SNI, where  `SSLv3` is removed, and where older cipher suites are removed **still** does not allow a secure connection, but instead throws a `SSLException` in `SSL_do_handshake()`.

If I try to force the old Android to use TLSv1.1, I get:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLContext TLSv1.1 implementation not found
```

My [research indicates](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) that `API 15` or lower is just never going to work with `TLSv1.1` and higher, but that `API 16` through `API 19` might work, but the newer protocol is not enabled by default.  `API 20` and higher, the newer protocol **is** enabled by default.

What needs to be done to allow a secure connection from httpclient on Android OS's in the `API 16` range?

Comment: The problem is more likely missing SNI support on these platforms. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782882/how-do-we-enable-sni-in-httpclient-4-4-on-android

Comment: hi,   @Dale  please check this question if possible thank you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse

Comment: @FaizalMohamed, I don't see how that question is related.  Can you expand upon the idea?

Comment: @Dale hi, sorry for confusing , its separate question if possible please help me by answering that question .. thanks. again sorry for confusing not related

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Thanks for the idea but I am using "4.4.1.2 release patched with SNI support".  I just checked SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java and it has the code referenced in the answer and so although `setHostname` is being called, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Dale: a packet capture of the connection might help to debug the problem so that one can see the actual differences of the TLS handshake.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I am able to precipitate the error on a new Android platform by restricting the protocol to `TLSv1`.  I conclude that the 3rd party web site needs `TLSv1.1` or higher, but the old Android platform only offers `TLSv1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `httpclient-android` code uses `getEnabledProtocols()` instead of `getSupportedProtocols()`.

The *[work around](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/issues/18)* that I employed was to get the [source code for smarek httpclient-android](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android/releases), pull that into a module of my project, remove the reference to the pre-built version of `httpclient-android`, then change one line in `SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java` :

```
    //final String[] allProtocols = sslsock.getEnabledProtocols();
    final String[] allProtocols = sslsock.getSupportedProtocols();
```

This had the effect of allowing connection to the third party web site I was trying to access on API's 16, 17, 18 and 19.

I think that Accessing TLSv1.1 or TLSV1.2 from API 15 or less is "impossible" unless you're willing to do some serious changes at the Android OS level.

But this simple change allows apps running on older Android versions to access sites that no longer support older SSL and TLSv1.