# TLS with Server Name Indication extension (RFC 3546) in Android

Tags: android, https, ssl, sni

I am building a Android app that needs to work with https. I have no problem doing a https connection to a https address that do not use TLS with [Server Name Indication extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546#section-3.1). But I need to do the connection to a https address that uses TLS with SNI extension.

What I did for https address that uses TLS with out hostname extension was:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://exampleurl.com/api");

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ssh_public_key", publickey));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
```

How do I add Server Name Indication extension in the TLS in Android. After research I found one post on stackoverflow but I cant get it to work with this information.

But its a bit on the way
"As far as I know, there is a partial support in Android SDK. The current situation is the following:

Since the Gingerbread release TLS connection with the HttpsURLConnection API supports SNI.
Apache HTTP client library shipped with Android does not support SNI
The Android web browser does not support SNI neither (since using the Apache HTTP client API)"

"Thanks for the help. I have tried the sni.velox.ch link using SSLCONTEXT(TLS) and SSLENGINE class available in the android sdk. I am getting the handshake."

[Android SSL - SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879894/android-ssl-sni-support)

This post gives the answer that this will work in Android but I cant get how to do it with HttpsURLConnection, SSLCONTEXT(TLS) and SSLENGINE.

Can any body provide an code example of how to set the Server Name Indication extension in the TLS?

Comment: Independently of SNI, I'm not sure what you're trying to do by sending an SSH public key in your header...

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer! But when it comes to the ssh public key I know that this is what i whant. The system that the app needs to call is advanst and very special. 

Do any one know how to do the https call with the host extension?

Thanks for answers