# Phonegap - Android https requests not working when built through Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, https, request

I'm struggling with https requests on Android.

We have a **valid SSL certificate** signed by CA that is well known and the https requests do not work, they come back with an error. Previously I built the apps using Phonegap build and there was no problem, now I needed to include a notification plugin (for toolbar notifications) and so the app needs to be build through Eclipse. The same url works fine with http, but as soon as https is used all requests fail.

Also the first time when I tried the link in the browser on my phone it came up with a popup warning about the certificate not being valid, but I am 100% sure the certificate is valid and signed correctly.

**Is there a simple way of making these https requests work without compromising on security?**

**Does anyone know what does phonegap build do differently than Eclipse?**

I've done some more research and it seems there may be a problem with the [intermediate certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340298/certificate-trusted-on-pc-but-not-in-android) not being installed. I'm still trying to find out whether we do have it installed. I thought I'll give an update just in case someone had the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone had the same problem, it was the intermediate certificate not installed. We installed it rebooted and it all works fine now.

Comment: Hello Matrina ..can you please guide me on whole process how to do with https. i am having the same issue when http get replaced with https.

Comment: Hi, all you need to do is make sure the server you're connecting to has a valid SSL certificate installed, including the intermediate certificate. In my case I had to contact the person who issues our certificates and had them help me re-install both parts of the certificate.