# "No certificates found" PWA app on Android, port 433

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I get that screen on Android while opening a PWA or directly with Chrome (or Internet Samsung):
[image]

I was reading: [How can I fix the "No certificates found - The app Chrome has requested a certificate" Android / Google Chrome issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005776/how-can-i-fix-the-no-certificates-found-the-app-chrome-has-requested-a-certif)

But in my case:

- the server is not IIS, is Nginx
- this happens in a PWA and also direct with the url in Chrome (or Internet Samsung)
- this happens in only 4 of almost 10.000 users! The app is being used for almost 10K users, and only 3 of them and including me have been with the problem, and it is not always...

To replicate the error I have to:

- reboot android
- uninstall the app
- install the app again
- open the app

I was debugging Chrome with phone connected through USB to my computer, inspecting with chrome, but nothing weird is seeing there, only in the phone.

Any hint or advice?

Comment: See Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005776/how-can-i-fix-the-no-certificates-found-the-app-chrome-has-requested-a-certif/43172454#43172454

Comment: but I put in my question that the server is not IIS

Comment: See Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005776/how-can-i-fix-the-no-certificates-found-the-app-chrome-has-requested-a-certif/43172454#43172454