# Face API Android SSL Exception

Tags: android, azure, face-api, sslexception

We are using Microsoft's Azure Face API for over 12 months now. But our low level API Android users (19) starting to get this error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:  != <*.cognitiveservices.azure.com> OR <*.cognitiveservices.azure.com>

It is working on level api 21+

Comment: check this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956663/why-does-android-get-the-wrong-ssl-certificate-two-domains-one-server

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a change to the MS certificates.
Face detection library is using deprecated httpClient libraries that don't support new certificate.

I replaced httpclient with OkHttp and I submitted a pull-request for fixing that (https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/pull/53).