# Self signed certificate exception Hostname Verification failed

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection, self-signed

I am trying to send data using httpsurlconnection. I imported .pem certificate into android keystore and created ssl context. Now everything is working fine except when I send some data over server from Android it is saying hostname  is not verified.

```
 HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
AssetManager assetManager = MainActivity.ctx.getAssets();
InputStream requestXML = assetManager.open("requestdump");         
String requestString = convertStreamToString(requestXML);
java.net.URL url = new URL("https://nn.nnn.nnn.nnn:xxxx");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier );
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
byte[] outputInBytes = requestString.getBytes("UTF-8");       
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write( outputInBytes );
os.close();             
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

This code is working and sending data on ssl enable server. I tried this code:

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier );
```

But I don't want to use this approach.

Without this approach I am getting Hostname  not verified. Can anybody suggest please how to send data over server using self signed certificate without using ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the certificate so its hostname is correct. That means starting again with a new keypair.

Comment: I was thinking of the same, but the issue is the same Certificate if I import into IE, it works. The server team is insisting that this certificate should work and is correct as IE (or any other browser) is able to hit the server.

Comment: one more funny thing happening is, now if I run my application from an Android Device (instead of Studio), I don't get Host Verification failed, but get the following error:
SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback

Not sure, why this is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a different certificate on android and Windows, because your Android application does not support [SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). And the certificate you get on Android is for a different host. Check [Android SSL - SNI support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879894/android-ssl-sni-support) for more details.